# GestureDetector changing the style properties of the child widget

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I want to make my custom-widget respond to touch, hence I used **GestureDetector's** onTap method. It's working but it is also changing the dimensions of my custom widget, which I don't want. I am posting some code and screen-shots to make the situation more clear.

What I want is this, just a MALE card (my custom-widget called **ReusableCard**).

[image]

After wrapping my ReusableCard widget in a GestureDetector, what I get is this.

[image]

I am sharing my code here. In this code I haven't used GestureDetector yet.

```
class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Center(
            child: Text('BMI Calculator')
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
```

> ```
>                 ReusableCard(activeCardColor,
>                     IconContents(FontAwesomeIcons.mars, 'MALE')),
>                 ReusableCard(activeCardColor,
>                     IconContents(FontAwesomeIcons.venus, 'FEMALE')),
> ```

```
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                ReusableCard(activeCardColor),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                ReusableCard(activeCardColor),
                ReusableCard(activeCardColor),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: bottomContainerColor,
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
            height: bottomContainerHeight,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The real meaty part of the code is in Blockquotes. Meaty Part after adding GestureDetector to MALE ReusableCard.

```
        GestureDetector(
          child: ReusableCard(activeCardColor,
              IconContents(FontAwesomeIcons.mars, 'MALE')),
        ),
        ReusableCard(activeCardColor,
            IconContents(FontAwesomeIcons.venus, 'FEMALE')),
```

I don't think if it's helpful but I am also sharing my ReusableCard code with you guys.

```
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard(this.colour, [this.cardChild]);

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: cardChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: colour,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have checked the documentation and I seem to be doing everything correctly. What I can infer from this is that I am messing up somewhere with the **Expanded** widget, but cannot correct it. Any help appreciated folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding the `GestureDetector` inside your `ReusableCard`, as a child of your `Expanded`.

```dart
class ReusableCard extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableCard(
    this.colour, {
    required this.cardChild,
    required this.onTap,
  });

  final Color colour;
  final Widget cardChild;
  final VoidCallback onTap;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Container(
            child: cardChild,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: colour,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

This way you won't need to wrap your `ReusableCard` with a `GestureDetector` breaking the `Expanded` widget.